# Me, myself or I

Tags: word-usage

What is the best word here? Is 'I' correct?

Have a read through and if you have any queries then please let Stephen or I know.

Answer (score 2):

What would it be without *Stephen*?

> Let me know
> Let I know
> Let myself know

Since "me" is correct here, it is also the one to choose in

> Let Stephen and me know

Answer (score 1):

It would be: please let Stephen or me know. because "Stephen" and "I" both are objects here. So we would use objective case of I which is obviously me.

For more information, see the Brittanica dictionary [here](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/When-to-Use-Me-and-I-#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20pronoun%20%22I%22%20when,way,%20either%20directly%20or%20indirectly.).

Comment: What did you mean to say?  Presumably not "Stephen and I both are adjectives here".